# Pandas read_csv error when file name starts with the letter f

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

So I'm using Pandas library on jupyter notebook and when I try to read my csv file and the name of the file starts with one of the letters a,b,c,d,e or f I get an error

For example when I use this command

```py
df = pd.read_csv('~\Documents\WorkBHO\final.csv')
```

I get this error

[Errno 2] File b'C:\Users\bho\Documents\WorkBHO\x0cinal.csv' does not exist: b'C:\Users\bho\Documents\WorkBHO\x0cinal.csv'

but when I change the name of the file to "pinal" for example it works just fine.

Why does this happen and how can I read the file without changing the first letter in its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash needs to be escaped in strings. You need to write either

```
df = pd.read_csv('~\\Documents\\WorkBHO\\final.csv')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'~\Documents\WorkBHO\final.csv')
```